# Don't Destroy On Load (creates multiple objects)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I use the DontDestroyOnLoad() in any GameObject e.g(Player, GameManager). When i go to another scene it always creates multiple GameObjects on the hierarchy from both player and gamemanager

```
    public static GameManager instance;
    private void Awake()
    {
       instance = this;
       DontDestroyOnLoad(instance); 
    }
```

Comment: What is the solution you tries so far? WHy are the multiple instances? Who manages the instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if instance is already there then destroy it. Here is code example:

```
public static GameManager instance = null;
private void Awake()
{
   if(instance == null)
   {
       instance = this;
       DontDestroyOnLoad(base.gameObject); 
   }
   else
   {
       Destroy(base.gameObject);
   }
}
```

Comment: while we are at it, is it wise to make Player like this, is there a more clean way to make the player appear on the other scene when i switch ? because for example the camera script is tied to the player because it moves whenever the player is moving, but when i make player a Non destroyable object the camera isn't tied to the player

Comment: and Thank you for your Answer tho <3

Comment: You can use Additive scene loading it will help

Comment: This works for things that actually are "singletons" meaning only a single instance should exist .. what if I want multiple instances but each if them only once? ;)

Comment: @derHugo I don't know or I don't understand what you said :) can you give example. I also here to learn :)